# display 2 classes style exam system jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'm working on exam system.

I need to display an user answer and then a correct answer.
In `Practice mode` behaviour would be a bit different, I mean it would show after clicking 'finish' button.

When I add `.ans` class, this is user choice, and `.corr` class is the realy correct answer, do I need to make both appear?

Any help please?

here is my Java Script, `JQuery` code

```css
.btn {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4, #f4f4f4);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4, #f4f4f4);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4, #f4f4f4);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4, #f4f4f4);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f4f4f4, #f4f4f4);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #666666;
  font-family: Courier New;
  color: #1c001c;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border: solid #1f628d 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.corr {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff329e, #ff329e);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff329e, #ff329e);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff329e, #ff329e);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff329e, #ff329e);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff329e, #ff329e);
}
.wrapper{
    margin-left: 330px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 2px solid brown;
    text-align:center;
    display: none;
  }
  
.ans{
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #AB0000, #AB0000);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #AB0000, #AB0000);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #AB0000, #AB0000);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #AB0000, #AB0000);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #AB0000, #AB0000);
}

.container{
  width:500px;
  height: 50px;
  
}

.wait{
  width: 330px;
  height: 800px;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid brown;
  display: none;
}


.ch{
    margin-top: 320px;
    margin-left: 360px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align:center;
    display: inline-block;
}
.choose{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #018dc4;
  -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
  border-radius: 9px;
  font: normal 21px/normal "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  word-spacing: 4px;
  background: rgba(74,134,232,0.7);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 2px 0 rgba(99,168,191,0.7) ;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 2px 0 rgba(99,168,191,0.7) ;
  text-shadow: -1px 3px 0 rgba(35,137,188,0.66) ;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  -o-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}
  #exm{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    display: block;
  }
  #myexam{
    display:inline-block;
  }

  #startIQ{
    width:250px;
    height:30px;
    margin:30px;
    padding:50px;
  }
body {background-color:#ccccb3;}
```

```html
 var s=0;
    var ENG_ans = [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,-1];
    var IQ_ans =[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1];

    function drowQuestion(idx,testEX)
      {

        var Q;
        if(testEX==0)
        {
          Q = ENGexam.Questions[idx];
        }
        else
        {
          Q = IQexam.Questions[idx];
        }
        
        //find div and change HTML
        HTMLtxt=" ";
        HTMLtxt = "<h2>Quesion "+ (idx+1) +"</h2>";
        HTMLtxt += "<h3>"+ Q.QuestionBody +"</h3>";
        HTMLtxt += "<form>";
        /*
        HTMLtxt += '<input type="button" name="answer" class="btn" id="a" value="'+Q.Answers[0]+'"/><br/>';
        HTMLtxt += '<input type="button" name="answer" class="btn" value="'+Q.Answers[1]+'"/><br/>';
        HTMLtxt += '<input type="button" name="answer" class="btn" value="'+Q.Answers[2]+'"/><br/>';
        HTMLtxt += '<input type="button" name="answer" class="btn" value="'+Q.Answers[3]+'"/><br/>';  
        HTMLtxt += '</form>';
        $("#myexam").append(HTMLtxt);  */
        var a ;
        if(testEX==0)
        {
         a = ENG_ans[idx];
        }
        else if(testEX==1)
        {
         a = IQ_ans[idx];
        }
         if(a == -1)
         {
          for(i=0;i<Q.Answers.length;i++)
           HTMLtxt += '<input type="button" name="answer" class="btn" id="'+i+'" value="'+Q.Answers[i]+'"/><br/>';
      } 
      else
      {
       for(i=0;i<Q.Answers.length;i++)
        if(a == i)
        {
            HTMLtxt += '<input type="button" name="answer" class="btn ans" id="'+i+'" value="'+Q.Answers[i]+'"/><br/>';
            answered++;
           }
           else
           {
            HTMLtxt += '<input type="button" name="answer" class="btn" id="'+i+'" value="'+Q.Answers[i]+'"/><br/>';
           }
      }
        HTMLtxt += '</form>';
        $("#myexam").append(HTMLtxt);

        $("#0").click(function() {

         // Q = exam.Questions[idx];
          $(this).addClass('ans');
          $("#1").removeClass('ans');
          $("#2").removeClass('ans');
          $("#3").removeClass('ans');
          
            //put this answer in an array
           // ans[idx] = 0;
           if(testEX==0)
           {
             ENG_ans[idx]=0;
           }
           else if(testEX==1)
           {
             IQ_ans[idx]=0;
           }
          
          
        });

        $("#1").click(function() {
          $(this).addClass('ans');
          $("#0").removeClass('ans');
          $("#2").removeClass('ans');
          $("#3").removeClass('ans');
        
        //  ans[idx] = 1;
           if(testEX==0)
           {
             ENG_ans[idx]=1;
           }
           else if(testEX==1)
           {
             IQ_ans[idx]=1;
           }
         
          
        });

        $("#2").click(function() {
          $(this).addClass('ans');
          $("#0").removeClass('ans');
          $("#1").removeClass('ans');
          $("#3").removeClass('ans');
        
        //  ans[idx] = 2;
            if(testEX==0)
           {
             ENG_ans[idx]=2;
           }
           else if(testEX==1)
           {
             IQ_ans[idx]=2;
           }
         
          
        });

        $("#3").click(function() {
          $(this).addClass('ans');
          $("#0").removeClass('ans');
          $("#1").removeClass('ans');
          $("#2").removeClass('ans');
        
        //  ans[idx] = 3;
           if(testEX==0)
           {
             ENG_ans[idx]=3;
           }
           else if(testEX==1)
           {
             IQ_ans[idx]=3;
           }
         
          
        });

      }
      function correct(idx){

      //  Q = ENGexam.Questions[idx];  
        if(testEX==0)
        {
          Q = ENGexam.Questions[idx];
        }
        else if(testEX==1)
        {
          Q = IQexam.Questions[idx];
        }  
           
        //find div and change HTML
        HTMLtxt = "<h2>Quesion "+ (idx+1) +"</h2>";
        HTMLtxt += "<h3>"+ Q.QuestionBody +"</h3>";
        HTMLtxt += "<form>";
        for(i=0;i<Q.Answers.length;i++)
        {
          HTMLtxt += '<input type="button" name="answer" class="btn" id="'+i+'" value="'+Q.Answers[i]+'"/><br/>';
          if(i==Q.CorrectAnswer)
            correctA = i;
        }
        HTMLtxt += '</form>';
        correctA = Q.CorrectAnswer;
        
       $("#myexam").append(HTMLtxt);
       
        $("input[name=answer]").each(function() {
          if(this.id == correctA)
          $(this).addClass('corr');
        });
        

      }


      function finishPractice(idx)
      {
       
      }
      onload = function () {

        document.getElementById("startIQ").style.display="none";
        //find something do something
        drowQuestion(index,testEX); 

        $("#fbtn").click(function(){
          $("#myexam").empty();
          index = 0;
          drowQuestion(index,testEX);
        });

        $("#pbtn").click(function(){
          $("#myexam").empty();
          index--;
          if(index < 0)
          {
            // index = ENGexam.Questions.length -1;
            if(testEX==0)
           {
            index = ENGexam.Questions.length -1;
           }
           else if(testEX==1)
           {
            index = IQexam.Questions.length -1;
           }
          }
            drowQuestion(index,testEX);
        });
        
        $("#nbtn").click(function(){
          $("#myexam").empty();
          index++;
          if(testEX==0)
           {                     
            if(index == ENGexam.Questions.length)
            {
              index = 0;
            }
           }
           else if(testEX==1)
           {
                       
            if(index == IQexam.Questions.length)
            {
              index = 0;
           }
           }
            drowQuestion(index,testEX);
        });
        
        $("#lbtn").click(function(){
          $("#myexam").empty();
         // index = ENGexam.Questions.length -1;
            if(testEX==0)
           {
            index = ENGexam.Questions.length -1;
           }
           else if(testEX==1)
           {
            index = IQexam.Questions.length -1;
           }
          drowQuestion(index,testEX);
        });
     
     
        $("#corr").click(function() {
          
          $("#myexam").empty();
           correct(index);
        });  

        $("#skip").click(function(event) {
         s++;
         $(".wait").empty();
         drowWait(index);
         //drow next question
          $("#myexam").empty();
          index++;
          if(testEX==0)
           {                     
            if(index == ENGexam.Questions.length)
            {
              index = 0;
            }
           }
           else if(testEX==1)
           {
                       
            if(index == IQexam.Questions.length)
            {
              index = 0;
           }
           }
            drowQuestion(index,testEX);
        });

        ///////////////////////////// Finish (close) Exam //////////////////////////////
        $("#fin").click(function(event) {

          clearInterval(t);
          min=00;
          sec=00;
          document.getElementById("timer").style.display="none";
          examFinish();
        });

        $("#p").click(function(){
         $(".ch").css('display', 'none');
         $(".wrapper").css('display', 'inline-block');
         $(".wait").css('display', 'inline-block');
         $("#skip").hide();
         flag = 0;
         set_timer();
        });

        $("#e").click(function(){
         $(".ch").css('display', 'none');
         //show exam div (as practice div, but without hint button)
         $(".wrapper").css('display', 'inline-block');
         $(".wait").css('display', 'inline-block');
         $("#corr").hide();
         flag=1;
        });
      
      }

</script>
</head>

<body background="#ccccb3">
 <div class="ch">
  <input type="button" class="choose" value="Exam Mode" id="e"/>
  <input type="button" class="choose" value="Practice Mode" id="p"/>
 </div>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div id="myexam" class="exam"></div>


  <div class="container">
   <div id="exm" class="exam">
          
         <input type="button" class="control" value="First" id="fbtn"/>
          <input type="button" class="control" value="Prev" id="pbtn"/>
          <input type="button" class="control" value="Next" id="nbtn"/>
          <input type="button" class="control" value="Last" id="lbtn"/>
          <input type="button" class="control" value="Finish Exam" id="fin"/>
          <input type="button" class="control" value="Hint" id="corr"/>
          <input type="button" class="control" value="Skip" id="skip"/>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <br/>
  </div>


  <div class="skip">
         
  </div>

  <div id="startIQ">
    <input type="button" value="start IQ exam" id="strtIQ"/>
  </div>

 </div>
 <div class="wait">
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is a lot of code for us to wade through. Do you think maybe you could [edit] your question to remove the parts of the code that aren't related to what you're asking about? When you say you want to "display 2 classes", do you mean that you want to add two classes to the same element (certainly possible), or use the classes already assigned to elements to select those elements so that you can make them visible (also possible)?

Comment: I didI need to make .append() function to work permanently